# Авто-заполняемое поле по предыдущей строке

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, в которую загружаются данные по пяти полям.

Необходимо создать поле, которое бы автоматически (Persisted) заполняло поле по предыдущей строке.

**формула=ABS(значение данной строки 2 поля - значение предыдущей 2 поля)/ABS(значение данной строки 1 поля - значение предыдущей строки 1 поля)**.

Заранее прошу прощения за "нечитабельность", к сожалению, не могу вставить таблицу. Буду рад любой подсказке.

Comment: [справка по форматированию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). внести исправления в вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 2):

Тут не обойтись без триггера, так как вычисляемый столбец не может быть подзапросом.
Цитата из https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

> Вычисляемый столбец вычисляется на основе выражения, в котором могут использоваться другие столбцы той же таблицы. Выражение может быть именем невычисляемого столбца, константой, функцией или любым их сочетанием, соединенным одним или несколькими операторами. Выражение не может быть вложенным запросом.

В свою очередь, пользовательская функция, используемая для вычисляемого столбца, также не должна осуществлять доступ к пользовательским и системным данным.
Цитата из https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186755(v=sql.120).aspx

> Вычисляемый столбец, который обращается к определяемой пользователем функции, может быть включен в индекс, если функция имеет следующие значения свойств:
> IsDeterministic = true
>
> IsSystemVerified = true (если вычисляемый столбец не материализован)
>
> UserDataAccess = false
>
> SystemDataAccess = false

Решением может быть использование триггера INSTEAD OF INSERT, в котором значение вычисляемого столбца будет вычисляться исходя из текущих значений и последних вставленных значений

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins ON tbl
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cur1 int, @cur2 int
    DECLARE @prev1 int, @prev2 int
    SELECT TOP 1 @prev1 = a, @prev2 = b FROM dbo.tbl ORDER BY id desc --предыдущие значения выбираются по автоинкрементному id
    SELECT @cur1 = a, @cur2 = b FROM inserted --текущие значения
    IF @cur1=@prev1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl(a,b,c,d,e)
        SELECT a,b,c,d,e
        FROM inserted
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl(a,b,c,d,e,f) 
        SELECT a,b,c,d,e, cast(abs(@cur2-@prev2) as float)/abs(@cur1-@prev1) 
        FROM inserted
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию [LAG](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_lag_and_lead_functions.html). Она появилась в SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Насколько я знаю Lag/Lead используются для вывода данных, в авто-вычисляемые поля их не вставить

Comment: Тогда напишите функцию (UDF).